# Centering page numbers in front of a small header image - Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, headers

[image: Word screenshot]

I've got a document with Word page numbers in the top right of the header. Behind the page numbers, I've placed some little circles (a .png), as a background for the page numbers themselves. The numbers 1-9 are centered perfectly on the circle, but 10+ plus are shifted off-center because of the multiple digits. Is there a way to keep ALL page numbers centered on these little circles?

Comment: Is your page number in a textbox of the width of the large circle and positioned over top of the png image?  If so, text is centred withiin the textbox it should also be appear centred in the circle (ie no need for section break at page 10).

Comment: Yeah, I would have thought that the number existed in a text-box, but evidently that's not how Word creates page numbers. The numbers exist as if they are just aligned text.

Answer (score 0):

There's no automatic way to do this, but you could manually insert a Section Break at the end of the ninth page and then setup the Header for pages 10 and beyond differently.

Comment: Interesting! This might work. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert a text box that's the same width and height as the diameter of the circle where you want the page number to appear, remove the background fill color, remove the borders, add a page number field, adjust the settings of the paragraph inside the text box so that the text is vertically and horizontally centered, and superimpose the text box over the circle.

Personally, though, I'd insert the circles as Word shapes instead of background graphics. You can then right-click the circle that you want the page number to appear in, select **Add Text**, and insert a page number field. The text should already be set so that it's horizontally and vertically centered inside the shape. However, you'll probably want to open the **Paragraph** dialog box for the paragraph inside the shape, remove any space before and after, and set the line spacing to **Single**. When you're done, you can select all the various circles and group them if you want. After the whole thing is formatted and positioned where you want it, you can even save it as a Page Number Building Block for later reuse.